# Multiplying two fields from a for loop

Tags: php

I want to multiply two fields. Below I fetch the needed values from a for loop. In total there are 54 fields in the database, 0 to 53. I need to multiply 9 and 11 and need to save store them in one variable:

```
<tbody>
<?php
    for($i=0;$i<$count_rd;$i++) {
?>

<tr  class="odd_gradeX">

<?php
    for($j=0;$j<=53;$j++){  // 0 3 4 7 9 17 18 19 20 21 22
    if(($j != 1) && ($j != 2) && ($j != 10) &&  ($j != 5) && ($j != 6) && ($j != 8) && ($j != 11) && ($j != 12)
    && ($j != 13) &&  ($j != 14) && ($j != 15) && ($j != 16)
    && ($j != 23) &&  ($j != 24) && ($j != 25) && ($j != 26) && ($j != 27) && ($j != 28) && ($j != 29)
    && ($j != 30) &&  ($j != 36) && ($j != 37) && ($j != 38) && ($j != 39)
    && ($j != 31) && ($j != 32)  && ($j != 33) && ($j != 34) && ($j != 35)&& ($j != 40) && ($j != 41) && ($j != 42)
    && ($j != 43) && ($j != 44) && ($j != 45) && ($j != 46) && ($j != 47) && ($j != 48) && ($j != 49)
    && ($j != 50) && ($j != 51) && ($j != 52) && ($j != 53)){
?>

<?php
    if(($j == 9)||($j == 17)||($j == 18) ||($j == 19) ||($j == 20) ||($j == 21) ||($j == 22)){
?>

<td align="right">

<?php
    }
    elseif(($j == 3)){
?>

<td align="left">

<?php
    }
    else {
?>

<td align="center">

<?php
    }
?>

<?php
    if($result[$i][$j]!='') {
?>

<?php
    echo $result[$i][$j];
?>

<?php
    echo "&nbsp;";
        }
    }
?>

</td>

<?php
    }
?>

</tr>

<?php
    }  ?>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you want to do with the code, but you can help yourself using arrays to organize the code.

Example:

```
<?php
$rightNumbers = array(0, 3, 4, 7, 9, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22);
$leftNumber = array(9, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22);
echo '<tbody>';
for($i=0;$i<$count_rd;$i++)
{    
  echo '<tr class="odd_gradeX">';
  for($j=0;$j<=53;$j++)
  {
    if(in_array($j, $rightNumbers))
    {
      echo '<td align="right">';
    }
    else if(in_array($j, $leftNumber))
    {
      echo '<td align="left">';
    }
    else if($j === 3)
    {
      echo '<td align="center">';
    }

    // Result should be printed?
    if($result[$i][$j]!='') 
    {
      echo $result[$i][$j] . "&nbsp;";
    }
    echo '</td>';
  }
  echo '</tr>';
}
?>
```

You say you want to save a variable, not sure which one but hopefully this helps you get closer

Comment: i want to multiply two fields, $j=9 means its qty and $j=11 means cost i need to multiply the qty*cost and save into $j=53. normally $j=53 means description  but i don't need that field so i need to show the value of qty and cost in $j=53;

Comment: if mysql means i can use mysql_fetch_array function but here i don't know how to use in as400 db2 iserious.